# Issue Running RIA Services on IIS 5

Tags: iis, silverlight-3.0, web-deployment-project

I'm setting up an environment for testing a Silverlight app with RIA Services in IIS 5.1. I'm getting an error message on the first service call saying "The specified resource was not found."

This only occurs when I deploy the project to my local IIS 5 setup, it works fine in the Visual Studio hosted web server.  I was having this issue with IIS 6 too but fixed the issue when I selected the virtual directory and selected "Convert to Application."  Problem is, IIS 5 doesn't have this function (that I can find, anyway.)

Anyone have experience deploying RIA Services on IIS 5?  Scouring the web I've only found related issues with Azure and other fixes that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find life less painful running Windows Server 2008 in a virtual machine.  (I don’t think the developers of RIA will be running on XP these days!)

If you have other reasons, upgrading your machine to windows 7 will give you a version of IIS more like what you get on a server, however using a virtual machine is lower risk.

*Sorry for the bad news, but XP is rather old….  (However I still have 2 machines running it)*

Comment: XP may be old but it's the client's standard so I have no choice but to use it (at least it's not our other client, they're on Win 2k!)  I did set up a VirtualBox with XP for my testing though, just trying to figure out what tweaks are necessary to the config to get it running.

Comment: but the backend should run on a server and XP is not a server OS

Comment: Actually that solves my problem: their server is 2003 with IIS 6 so I don't need to get this running on 5. Thanks! (Just assumed since XP was the standard that was the OS running on their server, ha.)